# How to fix incorrect postcodes when the adress is correct

Tags: r, duplicates

I am cleaning a company file that contains the adresses and postal codes of the companies.

Some companies are added multiple times, however the postal codes differ. This is probably caused by human errors, but makes working with the dataset very difficult.

The dataset would look something like this:

```
Company  |  Adress        | Postal Code  
Company1 | Limestreet     | 4444ER  
Company1 | Limestreet     | 4445ER  
Company2 | Applestreet    | 3745BB
```

I would like to check which companies have different postal codes. Since the companynames are often spelled differently too (also human errors), it would be best to check this based on matching addresses.

I've tried to solve with tidyverse, but it's not working. My plan was to find all the faulty postal codes and correct them manually. However, if there are too many, I might have to find a way to do it more efficiently. So not only would I like to ask advise on how to detect the errors, but I'd also like to ask advise on how to correct it in R. Maybe point me towards some good packages or pages describing how to fix it?

```
df2 <- df1 %>%  
    select(Adress PostalCode) %>%  
    group_by(Adress) %>%  
    summarise( n())
```

To create a mock example of the dataset:

```
company <- c("company1", "company1", "company2", "company2", "company3")
Address <- c("Limestreet", "Limestreet", "Applestreet", "Applestreet", 
"Pearstreet")
Postal_code <- c("4444ER", "4445ER", "3745BB", "3745BC", "8743IJ")

trail_data <- data.frame(company, Address, Postal_code)
```

Comment: Please provide code to make a reproducible example

Comment: Do you have  list of codes that are correct ones

Comment: Sorry, will do that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were close with your code, but I would just show the ones that have different lines. This will show you the ones to focus on.

```
trail_data %>%
  select(Address, Postal_code) %>%
  group_by(Address) %>%
  unique() %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a little more information from your database to get the final answer, BUT you can start by writing a little code that identifies if, when sorted, there is a discrepancy in the postal codes.  Note that I added one more row of data (company 3) that serves as a "non-discrepant" instance.

I created a new variable called `same` which is equal to 1 if company name and address match for any pair of rows, but 0 otherwise.  You can use this information with other data (which we don't have) to determine which value might be the correct one.

```
company <- c("company1", "company1", "company2", "company2", "company3","company3")
Address <- c("Limestreet", "Limestreet", "Applestreet", "Applestreet", 
                                 "Pearstreet","Pearstreet")
Postal_code <- c("4444ER", "4445ER", "3745BB", "3745BC", "8743IJ","8743IJ")

trail_data <- data.frame(company, Address, Postal_code)

trail_data$same<-ifelse(trail_data$company==lag(trail_data$company, trail_data$Address==lag(trail_data$Address,1) &   trail_data$Postal_code!=lag(trail_data$Postal_code),0,1)
```